# How to cancel a Request/Response communication with a CancellationToken in MassTransit ESB?

Tags: c#, masstransit, cancellation

I have a simple masstransit request/response proof of concept. It consists of two apps: one is for message sending and the other is for message consuming.
The message sending app goes like this:

```
var basicClient=_busControl.CreateRequestClient<IRequest,IResponse>(queueUri, timeout);
return await basicClient.Request(new Request(json), token);
```

The `Request` method takes a `CancellationToken` as a second optional parameter.

The message consumer has the following code:

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IRequest> context)
{
      var outputJson = await _longRunningJob.Execute(context.Message.Input, context.CancellationToken);
      context.Respond(new Response(outputJson));
}
```

As we can see the `ConsumeContext` also has a `CancellationToken` field.

So the question is: how can I use these tokens?

In my message sending app I'd like to cancel waiting for the response, 
and in the message consumer I'd like to cancel waiting for the `_longrunningJob` completion.

1. When I try to pass the token to the `Request` method and then call `Cancel()` on my `CancellationTokenSource` I expect the method to throw `OperationCancelledException`, but I just get the response!
2. I've also tried to pass an already cancelled token to this method, but nothing happened.
3. Then I've looked at Masstransit's source code and found out that token.ThrowIfCancellationIsRequested() is not called anywhere!

So, please tell me, am I doing something wrong here and there is another way to deal with CancellationTokens, or it is just a Masstransit's bug?

Comment: You need to throw that "token.ThrowIfCancellationIsRequested()", otherwise your async task will never know, whether canceled or not.

Comment: In the requestor you can specify a timeout, I think it is better than using cancellation tokens. Not sure about the consumer, it is just regular async/await there with your long running task, nothing to do with MassTransit. I am not sure if consumer's cancellation token has any request on the requestor. I think the proper way of informing your requestor that something happened in the consumer, is to send a proper response message instead of using technicalities.

Comment: @x... I don't need to call that method, but MassTransit should, i think.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev: Why is using a timeout better than using cancellation tokens? They are used for different reasons and I wonder, how can u use a timeout, when a user just presses the "Cancel" button in the UI.

Comment: @DanielVygolov when user clicks on "cancel" I will handle it properly and return it inside my response message. This is part of the business, no need to involve technicalities into it.

Answer (score 1):

The `CancellationToken` that is passed into the Request is to cancel the request itself, it's not passed onto the Consumer.

We managed to Cancel the Consumer using the following approach:

1. Add Expiry Date header to the Request (UtcNow + timeout)
2. In the Consumer compare the ExpiryDate header to UtcNow and if it older then exit the method